# Avoiding a constant "stop, build, up" loop when developing with Docker locally

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've recently delved into the wonder that is Docker and have set up my containers using `docker-compose` (an Express app and a MySQL DB).

It's been great for sharing the project with the team and pushing to a VPS, but one thing that's fast becoming tedious is the need to stop the running app, `docker-compose build` then `docker-compose up` any time there are changes to the code (which I believe is also creating numerous unnecessary images?).

I've scoured about but haven't found a clear-cut way to get around this, barring ditching Docker-compose locally and using `docker run` to run the Express app pointing to a local DB (which would do away with a lot of the easy set up perks that come with Docker, such as building the DB from scratch).

Is there a Nodemon-style way of working with Docker (images/containers get updates automatically when code changes)? Is there something obvious I'm missing? Or is my approach the necessary "evil" that comes with working on a Dockerised app?

Answer (score 0):

You can mount a volume to your source directory for local development. Any changes on the host will be reflected in the container. https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

You might consider separate services for deployment/development. I usually have a separate service which mounts the source directory and installs test dependencies inside the container.